# jQuery AJAX image upload on file input element

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to upload image automatically upon selecting an image via file select box submit to php via AJAX then return it's temp folder location to display this in a div element.

There are many other input elements inside the same form and I only want to do this for image preview.

Is there a way we can do this via jQuery AJAX?

I presume you have to use something like onChange event...
Is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure you want to incur the time it takes to send my 12 megapixel image all the way to your server, and back again, just to show me a preview?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you will have to do a `jQuery.bind()` on the `change` event for this.

I think this is the behaviour you are after:

http://jsfiddle.net/cMEb2/2/

Be aware that for security reasons some browsers are picky about access to the `input[type=file]` tag, so you may not be able to read (or change) its properties as readily as for other DOM elements. You can read some of these effects in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_select).

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous file uploads are not really something to be desired, because to create a preview, you would need to upload the file in advance.
However, you might want to check this article. It could be of some help:

http://tomas.epineer.se/archives/3